# Orientation of an $n$-pseudomanifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, orientation

I was reading the following [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669806001909) which had the following useful definition of an oriented $n$-pseudomanifold (Recall, an $n$-pseudomanifold is a simplicial complex where each $n-1$-simplex is contained in at most two $n$-simplicies).

An $n$-pseudomanifold is said to be oriented if

- each $n$-simplex is oriented and
- for any $(n − 1)$-simplex $\tau$ contained in two $n$-simplices, the induced orientations on $\tau$ from the two $n$-simplices are opposed.

Is there a consistent way to orient any triangulation which is equivalent to a sphere?
I think I can construct such an orientation for the simplicies for the cross polytope but was wondering if a more general theorem is known.

Also is there a way to get an orientation to a barycentric subdivision given an orientation for a manifold?

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, every simplicial complex homeomorphic to a sphere is orientable. To prove this in the generality that you ask requires some hard work. Perhaps the most modern approach would be first to develop the topological theory of orientation as is done in most algebraic topology courses (such as Hatcher's book; for a more succinct and still very clear description I also like the appendix to Milnor's book). Then apply that theory to spheres and to simplexes.

And yes, for every orientable pseudo-manifold its first barycentric subdivision is orientable. This is quite elementary, you simply have to construct, by induction on dimension, a canonical way to define an orientation on the first barycentric subdivision of an oriented $n$-simplex that agrees inductively with the first barycentric subdivision of its boundary. If you've ever seen a proof of the excision theorem in the theory of singular homology then you've probably encountered this construction.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. For the first question, I would be happy to simply cite such a result if it is already known. Is such a citable theorem already known? Also, which book of Milnor's were you referencing?

Comment: The appendix to *Characteristic Classes* by Milnor and Stasheff.

Comment: The point is that one needs a topological theory of orientation to even state the topological version of Poincaré duality. Perhaps one might also be able to find an old simplicial version of Poincaré duality, which basically mimics Poincaré's original approach based on a simplicial theory of orientation, and that should contain what you are asking about; however, I don't know a good description of that original approach.